# Issue with HomeBloc Creation Halting App on Homepage due to Shared Preferences Dependent Use Cases

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, sharedpreferences, flutter-bloc, injectable

Upon attempting to initialize the HomeBloc using Injectable, which depends on specific use cases (storeTokenLocallyUseCase and retrieveTokenLocallyUseCase), I encountered a roadblock. These use cases are dependent on Shared Preferences, and their injection into HomeBloc is causing the application to halt during its initialization on the homepage.

```
@module
abstract class DatasourceModule {
  @singleton
  Future<SharedPreferences> get provideSharedPreferences async =>
      await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}

@module
abstract class UseCaseModule {
  @lazySingleton
  StoreTokenLocallyUseCase provideStoreTokenLocallyUseCase(
      SharedPreferences preferences) {
    return StoreTokenLocallyUseCaseImpl(preferences);
  }

  @lazySingleton
  RetrieveTokenLocallyUseCase provideRetrieveTokenLocallyUseCase(
      SharedPreferences preferences) {
    return RetrieveTokenLocallyUseCaseImpl(preferences);
  }
}

@Environment(PlatformType.mobile)
@injectable
class HomeBloc extends SideEffectBloc<HomeEvent, HomeState, HomeEffect> {
  final StoreTokenLocallyUseCase storeTokenLocallyUseCase;
  final RetrieveTokenLocallyUseCase retrieveTokenLocallyUseCase;
  var logger = TraceLogger();

  HomeBloc(this.storeTokenLocallyUseCase, this.retrieveTokenLocallyUseCase)
      : super(const HomeState(title: "My state of data")) {
    on<InitialData>((event, emit) {
      logger.i("HomeBloc - InitialData");
      emit(state.copyWith(title: "Click"));
      produceSideEffect(HomeEffect.displayError("Test error"));
    });
    on<OnButtonClicked>((event, emit) {});
  }
}
```

I expected the dependencies relying on Shared Preferences to be injected into HomeBloc seamlessly, enabling the app to continue functioning as expected without any interruption.